# Scheduling an httpTrigger function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to set the schedule field at function.json on my "httpTrigger" type function but it seems the timer functionality doesn't run. My goal is to have a function that could be even scheduled and manually started, if needed, without having to add another function just for scheduling.

```js
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "schedule": "0 0 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `HttpTrigger` does not support schedule. Only `TimerTrigger` supports schedule

Answer (score 2):

The only trigger type that you can schedule is `timerTrigger`.

So, if you need a piece of code to both run on schedule *and* be runnable from a nice URL, you will have to create two Functions with two trigger types.

If you don't need a nice HTTP URL, you can call a timer Functions manually, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949126/1171619).

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to have a function that could be even scheduled and manually started, if needed, without having to add another function just for scheduling.

As other members mentioned that `HttpTrigger` does not support schedule. For your requirement, you could create another function or manually invoke your function programmatically as Mikhail answered.

Per my understanding, you could leverage [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal) for a simpler approach to schedule your azure function.

```
GET https://{your-function-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1?code={your-function-key}

Or

GET https://{your-function-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1
Header x-functions-key:{your-function-key}
```

[image]