# Update function.json of Azure function programmatically from different azure function function. | Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am working on azure functions. I have two azure function one is http Api and the second one is timer trigger function hosted in same function app:

**Function.json of timer trigger function :**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to below functionality :

1. Change schedule : From function A at runtime I want to change the schedule time of timer function.

> Ex: In above *function.json* schedule is "0 */1 * * * *" **to** "0 */5 * * * *"
> 2. Enable/Disable : I want to enable/ disable timer function from Function A.
> 3. Input : provide input also to the request.

Is there any way I can achieve above points programmatically ?

Thank You!

Comment: I understand that you need to enable/disable the timer trigger schedule and change the schedule value from the HTTP Trigger Function? - Is that your ask?

Comment: Yes, Correct that is the ask.

Comment: you could have a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal

Answer (score 1):

> Change schedule : From function A at runtime I want to change the
> schedule time of timer function.

- *Firstly, Schedule in functions is used only in **Timer Trigger Function** you can't use it in HTTP function so you can't change the schedule through **HTTP Trigger Function** you can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50267608) for further details.*
- *Rather you can use Azure logic apps for changing the schedule value using logic apps for complete information here is the document for [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps).*
- *To enable or disable Azure function programmatically you need to change the format in app setting and add below code.*

  `AzureWebJobs.<FUNCTION_NAME>.Disabled : True`
- *You need to add the above code in `Function.JSON` file for further details you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal) which includes complete information regarding enable/disable azure function.*
- *Here is the output after testing in my local environment.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Point 2 ( using Logic apps with Service Bus ) I was able to complete flow.

For Point 1 : I am changing/ want to change the schedule of timer trigger function from a HTTP function. In the question I have mentioned the same. 

For Point 3 & 4 : I am still not clear that after doing these changes how I change the Environment variable .