# how to change value in the local.settings.json file in function app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-functions, c#-3.0

I'm using visual studio 2019 and I created the function app I need to change the value in the local.settings.json file when I run the function app that I want to change the ***schedule*** data Cron expression string dynamically

**JSON file**

```
 {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "schedule": "*/10 * * * * *"
  }
}
```

**function app:**

```
[FunctionName("Function3")]
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%schedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{            

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no solution** to set the schedule of Azure Function dynamically by code.

But you could do it using [Durable Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#monitoring), or change the value using [kudu API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575629/13586071).

Please check the answer of this question: [How to create dynamically schedule Azure function using c# in visual studio?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfb91a1c-5b25-4873-90a3-46da05a97bc0/how-to-create-dynamically-schedule-azure-function-using-c-in-visual-studio)